# Spark sql query to find many to many mappings between two columns of the same table ordered by maximum overlapedness

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to write a Spark sql query  or pyspark code to extract many to many mappings between two columns of the same table ordered by maximum overlapedness.
For example:

```
SysA   SysB
A        Y
A        Z
B        Z
B        Y
C        W
```

Which means there is therefore a M:M relationship between the above two columns.
Is there a way to extract all M:M combinations ordered by maximum overlapedness i.e values which share a lot among each other should be at the top? and discarding the one-one mappings like C W

```
Z maps to both A and B
Y maps to both A and B
A maps to both Y and Z
B maps to both Y and Z
```

Therefore both A ,B  AND X,Y have M:M relationships and C W Is 1:1. The order would be sorted by the count i.e 2 , in above example only mappings of two are there between A,B:X,Y hence both are 2.

Similar question:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa496933-e85a-4dfe-98df-b6c29ad812f4/sql-to-find-manytomany-combinations-of-two-columns

Comment: Do you mean something like `df.groupBy('SysA', 'SysB').count().filter("count<2").orderBy('count')`?

Comment: To extend the comment of @pythonic833, if you want to count `(A,W)` the same as `(W,A)` you can use some tricks like `df.groupBy(least("SysA", "SysB").as("val1"), greatest("SysA", "SysB").as("val1")).count().where("count > 1").orderBy(desc("count"))`. In this way you will get a single row as result : `{val1=A, val2=W, count=2}`. You can add an example of the expected result to your question

Comment: @pythonic833 no, this does not solve it as we need to do groupby for each of the columns and see the commanality to find the M:M columns.

Comment: @vinsce let me correct the example,  both columns are diffferent things

Comment: @vinsce corrected my example

Comment: The [similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa496933-e85a-4dfe-98df-b6c29ad812f4/sql-to-find-manytomany-combinations-of-two-columns) you shared has an accepted answer using `sql`. What is the difference between your question and this and if it is the same, have you tried running the similar question's `sql` answer on `spark-sql`?

Comment: @ggordon that solution uses many non spark MS specific constructs not possible in  spark

Comment: @ggordon also it does not order by count i guess

Answer (score 0):

AS you requested and simplified version of your similar [MSDN quesiton](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa496933-e85a-4dfe-98df-b6c29ad812f4/sql-to-find-manytomany-combinations-of-two-columns) identifying just M:M relationships and ordered.

The following approaches may be used on Spark SQL.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE SampleData (
      `SysA` VARCHAR(1),
      `SysB` VARCHAR(1)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO SampleData
      (`SysA`, `SysB`)
    VALUES
      ('A', 'Y'),
      ('A', 'Z'),
      ('B', 'Z'),
      ('B', 'G'),
      ('B', 'Y'),
      ('C', 'W');
```

**Query #1**

For demo purposes i have used `*` instead of `SysA,SysB` in the final projection below

```sql
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                *,
                (
                     SELECT
                          count(*)
                     FROM
                          SampleData s
                     WHERE s.SysA=sd.SysA
                ) SysA_SysB,
                (
                     SELECT
                          count(*)
                     FROM
                          SampleData s
                     WHERE s.SysB=sd.SysB
                ) SysB_SysA
            FROM
                SampleData sd
        ) t
    WHERE t.SysA_SysB > 1 AND t.SysB_SysA>1
    ORDER BY t.SysA_SysB DESC, t.SysB_SysA DESC;
```

```
| SysA | SysB | SysA_SysB | SysB_SysA |
| ---- | ---- | --------- | --------- |
| B    | Z    | 3         | 2         |
| B    | Y    | 3         | 2         |
| A    | Y    | 2         | 2         |
| A    | Z    | 2         | 2         |
```

---

**Query #2**
NB. Cross Joins should be enabled in spark i.e. setting `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled` as `true` in your spark conf

```sql
    SELECT
        s1.SysA,
        s1.SysB
    FROM
        SampleData s1
    CROSS JOIN
        SampleData s2
    GROUP BY
        s1.SysA, s1.SysB
    HAVING
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN s1.SysA = s2.SysA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) > 1 AND
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN s1.SysB = s2.SysB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) > 1
    ORDER BY
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN s1.SysA = s2.SysA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) DESC,
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN s1.SysB = s2.SysB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) DESC;
```

```
| SysA | SysB |
| ---- | ---- |
| B    | Z    |
| B    | Y    |
| A    | Z    |
| A    | Y    |
```

---

**Query #3 (Recommended)**

```sql
WITH SampleDataOcc AS (
    SELECT 
        SysA, 
        SysB, 
        COUNT(SysA) OVER (PARTITION BY SysA) as SysAOcc, 
        COUNT(SysB) OVER (PARTITION BY SysB) as SysBOcc 
     FROM 
        SampleData
)
SELECT
     SysA,
     SysB,
     SysAOcc,
     SysBOcc
FROM
     SampleDataOcc t
WHERE 
    t.SysAOcc > 1 AND 
    t.SysBOcc>1
ORDER BY 
    t.SysAOcc DESC, 
    t.SysBOcc DESC;
```

```
| SysA | SysB | SysAOcc   | SysBOcc   |
| ---- | ---- | --------- | --------- |
| B    | Z    | 3         | 2         |
| B    | Y    | 3         | 2         |
| A    | Y    | 2         | 2         |
| A    | Z    | 2         | 2         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/firR6anEec8JsYGC1htJrU/2)

Comment: are two queries different ways of doing the same?

Comment: how can it be achieved without a cartesian join

Comment: All queries achieve the same goal. I simply started by simplifying or writing a query that was not specific to mssql as shared in your desired answer to highlight the similarities.

Comment: As it pertains to your concerns about joins, I've updated the answer with `Query 3`

Comment: how are the counts coming to be 3? The order would be sorted by the count i.e 2 , in above example only mappings of two are there between A,B:X,Y hence both are 2.??

Comment: To further test the ordering, I added an additional record in the test DML ` ('B', 'G'),` as shown in the answer and fiddle above for reproducibility which now shows that element `B` in `SysA` maps to 3 elements in `SysB`

Comment: See fiddle with showing count of 2 with this record removed - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peoL3bF5i55CJ842Qu3nCT/0